# ng-bind-html doesnt works properly for html tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've already follwed [this topic](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

It works! From this

```
&lt;p&gt;9+555&lt;/p&gt;\r\n
```

to this `<p>9+555</p>`

it still leaves the HTML tag there.

How can I make those tags work as HTML not in text. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using &lt and &gt you should write `<p>` directly.

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myHTML = 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                        '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
    }]);
```

Here is a plunk showing the differences between your string and a correctly html-formated one http://plnkr.co/edit/RZmuzTilvBkU3oGUre7J

Comment: Could please explain why we should not use &lt and &gt?

Comment: I basically store "<p>9+555</p>" into the database but those "&lt,&gt" come from no where

Comment: They come from your server. The problem is how you get that string into your JS file.

Comment: You shouldn't use &lt; and $gt; because they are HTML [entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) and will be interpret as string when being parsed as HTML.

Comment: @ChanonDeeprasertkul i added a plunk to my answer so you more easily can see the differences.